# Casting input arguments to correct type

Tags: python, arguments, sys

I have a function in a file that receives different types of parameters (int, strings, dictionaries, lists...)

Usually I call this function from another one, passing the right parameters, but I would like to also be able to call it from the console (for testing purposes)

The problem is that the input arguments are stored as strings, so I cannot directly pass them to the function.

Is there a way of automatically passing the parameters from the console to the function keeping the correct format?

```
import sys

def myfunction(mystring, myint, mydict, mylist):
    # check that types are correct
    assert type(mystring) is str
    assert type(myint) is int
    assert type(mydict) is dict
    assert type(mylist) is list

    # print input parameters
    print mystring
    print myint 
    print mydict
    print mylist

def main(args):
    print args
    myfunction(*args)   # pass the parameters to the function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])  # discard 1st element which is the filename
```

To call my function from console I just do:

```
python myfile.py "hello" 5 {'age':30} [1,2,3,4]
```

The first `assert` succeds since it expects a string, but the second one fails since it expects an int.

The `print args` from the main function returns `['hello', '5', '{age:30}', '[1,2,3,4]']`  (so arguments have been parsed correctly, but they are stored as strings).

I just need to convert them to the right format.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps, you can use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass them as a python list:

```
python myfile.py "['hello',5,{'age':30},[1,2,3,4]]"
```

and then get the arguments using `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast,sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1])
    main(args)
```

Now `args` is a `list` worth `['hello', 5, {'age': 30}, [1, 2, 3, 4]]`

To be really portable between shells (windows, Linux), the above approach is preferred: double quotes to protect the argument, simple quotes to protect strings. Doing it the other way round works with Linux/MSYS shells but not with Windows (single quotes are not really quotes in windows)

Comment: Worked. I added some verification that the input param is a string containing a list with parameters in the correct format before calling the function.